# can't access to updated state with appanded element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm creating JSX element with the onClick on the button:

```
      <div onClick={() => addWeek()} >
        add week
      </div>
```

then I update state (add new items to array) :

```
//my state that has one object initially (I want to add more)
  const [weekly, setweekly] = useState([
    {
      id: 'n1',
      day_week: null,
      start_time: null,
      end_time: null,
    },
  ]);
    const addWeek = () => {
        setweekly([
          ...weekly,
          {
            id: `n${weekly.length + 1}`,
            day_week: null,
            start_time: null,
            end_time: null,
          },
        ]);
    }
```

after I create JSX element I have an onChange event on that element :

NOTE: This element created with onClick and I have two objects inside my state now.

```
       <select
            onChange={(event) => handleWeekly(event)}
            id={`n${weekly.length + 1}`}
          >
//Some options
         </select>
```

but in here I can't access the updated state I get one object.

```
  const handleWeekly = (event) => {
   // I get one object
    console.log(weekly);

  };
```

CODE SAND BOX :
https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-nightingale-l6qg3?file=/src/App.js:0-1372

Comment: I am confused. Your button element has onClick or onChange ? It should have onClick

Comment: It's select option I have to change it my bad

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-ganguly-43l8v?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: your example isn't true because add week should create a new select  example : https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-nightingale-l6qg3?file=/src/App.js:0-1372

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this problem differently. Instead of putting markup in the state you can map through your data and render your components this way:

```
export default function App() {
  const [weeks, setWeek] = useState([
    {
      id: "n1",
      day_week: null,
      start_time: null,
      end_time: null
    }
  ]);
  const addWeek = () => {
    setWeek([
      ...weeks,
      {
        id: `n${weeks.length + 1}`,
        day_week: null,
        start_time: null,
        end_time: null
      }
    ]);
  };

  const handleWeekly = (event) => {
    console.log(weeks);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div onClick={() => addWeek()}>add week</div>
      {weeks.map((week) => {
        return (
          <select
            onChange={(event) => handleWeekly(event)}
            id={`n${week.id}`}
            key={`n${week.id}`}
          >
            <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            <option value="saab">Saab</option>
            <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
          </select>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

It's easier to keep track of your state this way.

[Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-wildflower-b72ij?file=/src/App.js:820-867)